# Jquery flipping class data for RTL

Tags: jquery, css, glyphicons

I need to flip twitter bootstrap glyphicons with Jquery.
For example if the document is RTL (I check inside div, not in  dir attribute)
Then I will flip glyphicons from right to left and from left to right.

I tried this:

```
function rtlChange() {
    var textDirection = $("#mydiv").data("direction");
    if (textDirection == "rtl") {
        $("i.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right").toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-left');
        $("i.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-left").toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-left glyphicon-chevron-right');
         $("i.glyphicon.glyphicon-arrow-right").toggleClass('glyphicon-arrow-right glyphicon-arrow-left');
        $("i.glyphicon.glyphicon-arrow-left").toggleClass('glyphicon-arrow-left glyphicon-arrow-right');
        $("i.glyphicon.glyphicon-hand-right").toggleClass('glyphicon-hand-right glyphicon-hand-left');
        $("i.glyphicon.glyphicon-hand-left").toggleClass('glyphicon-hand-left glyphicon-hand-right');        
     }
}
```

This changes "glyphicon-chevron-right" to "glyphicon-chevron-left". But due to next line, all "glyphicon-chevron-left" changes to "glyphicon-chevron-right".

I need rights to be left and left to be right once.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/qc88s/19/

How can do this Jquery ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in very simple way as fellow:

```
function rtlChange() {

    var textDirection = $("#mydiv").data("direction");
    if (textDirection == "rtl") {
        $("i.glyphicon").each(function( index ) {

            if($(this).hasClass("glyphicon-chevron-right")){
                $(this).removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");
                $(this).addClass("glyphicon-chevron-left");
            }else{
                $(this).removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-left");
                $(this).addClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qc88s/26/

Answer (score 0):

Store the selectors' selections first then do the changes:

```
function rtlChange() {
    var textDirection = $("#mydiv").data("direction");
    if (textDirection == "rtl") {
        //Get all selectors' selections first
        var rightChevrons = $("i.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right");
        var leftChevrons = $("i.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-left");
        rightChevrons.toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-left');
        leftChevrons.toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-left glyphicon-chevron-right');

        /* Do the same with the below
        $("i.glyphicon.glyphicon-arrow-right").toggleClass('glyphicon-arrow-right glyphicon-arrow-left');
        $("i.glyphicon.glyphicon-arrow-left").toggleClass('glyphicon-arrow-left glyphicon-arrow-right');
        $("i.glyphicon.glyphicon-hand-right").toggleClass('glyphicon-hand-right glyphicon-hand-left');
        $("i.glyphicon.glyphicon-hand-left").toggleClass('glyphicon-hand-left glyphicon-hand-right');
        */

    }
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/qc88s/21/